# React-native-firebase in-app-messaging not working

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I've set up firebase integration as explained here: https://rnfirebase.io/
Anonymous auth works, Firestore CRUD works.

I can't get in-app-messaging to work. I've set up it as described [here](https://rnfirebase.io/in-app-messaging/usage).

I've imported it to the root of my app:

```
import inAppMessaging from '@react-native-firebase/in-app-messaging'
```

Made sure notifications are not suppressed in the `componentDidMount`:

```
console.log(inAppMessaging().isMessagesDisplaySuppressed)
inAppMessaging().setMessagesDisplaySuppressed(false)
```

I've followed [these instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/get-started?authuser=0#get_your_apps_instance_id) to get an installation id and run "Test on device" from firebase admin panel. When I'm running this test, Firebase admin panel says "Campaign is ready for testing" but I'm not receiving any notifications or error messages in my app. Neither on device nor simulator.
The regular "Campaigns" not working either. I've [set schedule](https://prnt.sc/sxwklx) to "on_foreground" and "app_launch". Neither of these events displays the in-app messaging.

Firebase in-app-messaging campaign analytics shows "0 clicks" and "0 impressions".

Answer (score 1):

After following the documention, not message was showing. then, I just reinstalled the app. And installed again. It works.

Comment: is there any problem in production build if users do not uninstall app?

Comment: no. not that I am aware of

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with the configuration.

you can reconfigure in-app-messaging and test

you can [follow this instruction](https://medium.com/@deshan.m/react-native-firebase-in-app-messaging-ios-5e272dee39bb)